# Run several matlab instances in a nohup bash script

Tags: bash, matlab, terminal, nohup

I'm trying to do something like the following.
Right now, I connect via ssh to a remote machine and run my analysis with nohup command as

```
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1 &
```

Now I want to write a script that runs in background several nohup commands one after the other one.
I managed to do

```
#!/bin/bash
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r "mycode;quit;" > output.txt
```

But not only the code works with one CPU only, but also it goes in an infinite loop and never finishes the job.

I can I solve that?
It is important that I could close the terminal after launching the script.sh

EDIT:
Thanks to you I manage to do and let the following thing to work well

```
ssh user@ipaddress
screen
cd folder1/
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1 &
exit
screen
cd folder2/
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1 &
exit
```

Now is it possible to do a script of that? Because I noticed that any time I type `screen` I have to press Enter right after.

EDIT2: @Peter
I did what you suggested

```
#!/bin/bash
cd folder1/
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r "mycode;quit;" < /dev/null  > output.txt
cd folder2/
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r "mycode;quit;" < /dev/null  > output.txt
```

But only the first matlab runs, how is it possible?

Comment: How about using [`screen`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm)?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis sorry can you be more specific I've never use the screen command :(

Comment: that's why I provided a link to the documentation :) There you can read that "Screen will allow you to have multiple screens doing different tasks without having to connect (SSH) multiple times into the same computer." and also "[...] detach [...] will keep the screen active, even when logging off and can be reattached the next time you connect.". So it allows you to open multiple terminal sessions over the same SSH connection, and the tasks you run in each of them will not terminate when you disconnect the SSH connection. I think that's sort of what you're trying to do, correct?

Comment: @Nicholas I actually don't see a part of your second script that could make it go infinite and there's nohup too. Did you make something other than that?

Comment: @konsolebox no I didn't just that and the code never stops (?)

Comment: Your very first nohup line appears to do the right thing.  What's wrong with just running that line multiple times?

Comment: The -r version fails because it's still trying to read from stdin.  If you add a `< /dev/null` to that line, it will work as well as the first one.

Comment: @Peter I know that my first line works, it is what I do now. But I want to write a script that run the nohup command one after the other without every time wait the end of one a start another one, that's all

Comment: It already doesn't (shouldn't) wait... You have nohup and `&`.  As soon as you run that nohup line, you get back a command prompt, where you can run another one.  So your script can just have that nohup line as many times as you want, and they'll all launch at the same time.  Unless I'm missing the real problem you're having?

Comment: @Nicholas With your first edit does your matlab really run? I mean if it doesn't pause since it's still running as a daemon and no input is placed on it..

Comment: @konsolebox no it doesn't Im sure it's a problem related to the fact that when I type screen I also have to press Enter afterwards, and in a script I can't

Comment: @Nicholas So matlab asks for TTY input as well? Try `expect` if that's the case. Or was it `screen` that asks for enter key?

Comment: @konsolebox screen asks for input (press spacebar or enter)

Answer (score 4):

Compiling all suggestions and ideas you could try these:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@ipaddress "
cd folder1/
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1 &
cd folder2/
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1 &
"
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@ipaddress "
cd folder1/
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r 'mycode;quit;' < /dev/null  > output.txt 2>&1 &
cd folder2/
nohup matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r 'mycode;quit;' < /dev/null  > output.txt 2>&1 &
"
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@ipaddress "
cd folder1/
screen -dm matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1
cd folder2/
screen -dm matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < mycode.m > output.txt 2>&1
"
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@ipaddress "
cd folder1/
screen -dm matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r 'mycode;quit;' < /dev/null  > output.txt 2>&1
cd folder2/
screen -dm matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r 'mycode;quit;' < /dev/null  > output.txt 2>&1
"
```

You could also try `expect` to control matlab instead of sending `mycode.m` or using `-r` to it.

Try doing `nohup` on `screen` as well. And I think you no longer need to add `&` to it since `screen` runs as a daemon by default already.

Comment: Thank you for your post, even though I think I found a nice solution that I'm gonna post.

Answer (score 1):

Thank all of you for helping me.
I think I've found that I was looking for.

1. I `ssh` into my machine
2. create a new screen with the command `screen -dmS analysis`
3. run the script (see below) `nohup ./script.sh &`
4. close the screen `exit`
5. check the running with `top` (as usual :))

This is my `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r "cd folder1/; run('mycode.m'); quit"  < /dev/null  > output.txt
matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay -r "cd folder2/; run('mycode.m'); quit"  < /dev/null  > output.txt
```

The analyses run one after the other! Great!

Comment: I think S analysis is optional. You could just have `screen -dm`

Comment: Also, running `screen -dm` without arguments or commands would not create an interactive screen process. It would just be a lone screen on a background. The one that just worked was `nohup ./script.sh &`. I think it would still work even if you don't run `screen -dmS analysis`.